# Nhibernate foreign key constraint due to unexpected update of already inserted record

Tags: sql, nhibernate, transactions

This is a strange one replicated in the following code:

```
        using (ISession session = RepositoryTestHelper.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            //session.BeginTransaction();

            UserRepo repo = new UserRepo(session);
            CompanyRepo cRepo = new CompanyRepo(session);
            var user = repo.FindByEmail("test.user@blah.com");
            user.CompanyAssociations.Add(new CompanyUserAssoc() 
                { 
                    User = user,
                    Company = cRepo.GetById(1)
                });
            repo.AddOrUpdate(user);

            //session.Transaction.Commit();
        }
```

And the relationship between user, company and CompanyUserAssoc is fairly straight forward:

For the company:

```
HasMany<CompanyUserAssoc>(x => x.UserAssociations).KeyColumn("User_id");
```

For the user:

```
HasMany<CompanyUserAssoc>(x => x.CompanyAssociations).KeyColumn("Company_id")
```

And for the association class itself:

```
References(x => x.Company).UniqueKey("CompanyId_UserId");
References(x => x.User).UniqueKey("CompanyId_UserId");
```

Now this is where I am baffled.  Notice in my initial code that the begin and commit trans calls are commented out.  This actually means the code will work! The CompanyUserAssoc is created and correctly references the user and the company with id of 1.  Great!

But... sadly when I put this in a transaction i get this error:

```
{"The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK3C47859753A62C6E\". The conflict occurred in database \"xxxx\", table \"dbo.Company\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

But why?  Well that's my question.  What i have see in the profiler is that it does this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [CompanyUserAssoc] SET Company_id = null WHERE Company_id = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1
```

Wait... what? NULL? Why is it setting the company id to null? and why is it only doing this when in a transaction?  What's "wrong" with my Nhibernate mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Since both collections are mapped as non-inverse ([the default](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping)) and the Company collection has no users, it will issue that update to clear the link table. Could you try setting the `UserAssociations` to inverse? Or, what I usually do when an explicit link table is involved, is set both `HasMany`s to inverse and simply work with the link table directly.

Comment: Setting both user and company HasMany statements/declarations to be inverse and then explicitly adding a CompanyUserAssoc entity prior to the commit, I am able to confirm that this works.
The frustration is that it works perfectly without a transaction involved and what I really want to achieve here is to add the new/updated entity to the user company collection (or to company user collection) and have nhib add this when required without the need to explicitly add this association/link (as it does with no transaction involved). 
Thanks for your response by the way!

Comment: Oh, you don't have to have the explicit link table. Just use a ManyToMany on each side and pick which side you want to be inverse. The non-inverse side would then "own" the association, so you'd only be able to add links through that side.

Comment: Not sure about the transaction vs. no transaction behavior...maybe all that does is change the order of the statements. Can you check if the update fires before the insert when not using a transaction?

Comment: Getting some odd behavior now after making changes and then undoing them (data has been deleted so can't see why). i.e. 
"object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave. Type: CompanyUserAssoc, Entity: CompanyUserAssoc"
I'm assuming that the transient instance is the new one, i.e. the assoc it refers to which has no id yet. Can't see why no FK error now!
However, when i looked at profiler before it was never running the update statement, only the insert when no trans

Comment: Hi dotjoe - got an update. Profiling shows exactly what it's doing.  Inserting the assoc, getting id from scope, then using that later on and getting the fk exception. By executing this sql manually with a begin and commmit around it (and updating the id) replicates the issue.  But doesn't give me any clues as to how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

This was a red herring in the end, a fish I have come to despise.  I had not noticed in my haste and dependence on intellisense that the UserAssocations property of the Company was not an IList but an IList!  yes I have stupidly chosen the Nhib map class instead of the domain class.. This weirdly didn't error in the way you would expect, and worked without a transaction, but why?

Well - Nhib was able to insert the assoc entry, but then believed it needed to update that same table with the id it had already inserted (because it somehow sees it as a different entity?). I would have expected a compilation error here in the map class itself as I was using the type, but no.  And without a transaction the sql generated works.

I would investigate more as to why, but I've answered this just to highlight a rare and silly mistake which can lead to a lot of investigation if missed.